# How to write if else statement in python win?

Tags: python

I'm a newbie to python. I want to write if else statements which consist many lines of coding. But once I write the first line of if else statement coding, I can't hit enter to write the next line. I search it up and find that most of other examples, if they hit the enter button and then the application will automatically give space to write the next line of if else code. So how to write it?

Here is the example of other codes that I got from internet.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pFHi.jpg)

As you can see, the application will proceed to read the next line of the coding statement while mine looks like this :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKWmV.png)

Please help me T^T

Comment: You're missing a colon after the `if` statement in the screenshot you posted. Also you should do your programming in a proper IDE like PyCharm, it'd be horribly painful to do all your coding in the interactive terminal like you're currently doing.

Comment: you need to add colon `:` if like this `if a==1:`. Then your shell will allow you to write the statement within the if block

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a colon `:` after the if statement:

`if a==3:`